# Upgrade from 1.3.1 to 2.0 with docker

Tags: docker, thingsboard

I am running docker with thingsboard 1.3.1 I would like to migrate to 2.0 but i cannot make it work.

I tried to trigger the upgrade script insite of the container. 
There I get the error:

```
Connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start
ThingsBoard upgrade failed!
```

I tried to run the script outsite of the container. There I get the error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'thingsboardInstallService': Unsatisfied 
dependency expressed through field 'databaseSchemaService'; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'sqlDatabaseSchemaService': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'installScripts'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'installScripts': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through field 'ruleChainService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'baseRuleChainService': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'relationService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'baseRelationService': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'entityService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'baseEntityService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through field 'deviceService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'deviceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through field 'cacheManager'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [org/thingsboard
/server/dao/cache/CaffeineCacheConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method 
failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
ThingsBoard upgrade failed!
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile you used to build the image?  Usually the solution would be to build a new image with a new version of the software, then launch a new container against the new image.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the Thingsboard Database. Replacing the Docker Image will not update the Database. So the only way to update the platform I found is: To install Thingsboard 1.4.0 outside a docker container and initiate the Update script with  "$ sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/upgrade.sh --fromVersion=1.4.0"(example for Linux). This Updates the Database of Thingsboard. Afterwards it is possible to simply replace the Docker container with a prebuild Thingsboard 2.0 Image.
I couldn't find a way to update the database from inside the container.

Comment: Hand-upgrading the software inside a running container is not a best practice.  **If you stop and delete the container this upgrade will be lost.**  (And you need to stop and delete containers somewhat routinely.)

Comment: I didnt mean to update the container. As I wrote before, the database structure needed to be updated and I couldn't find a way to trigger this update using the provided images. Apologize if I haven't made myself clear enough.